# rails belong_to which class to choose

Tags: ruby, orm

There is a model relation like this.

```
class A
belongs_to :ref_config,:class_name => 'User'
end
```

My question is :
   the A has a attribute named flag,  now i want to  create a function  like this:

if flag == 1, I want the class A like this  `belongs_to :ref_config,:class_name => 'Department` and if flag == 2, i want the class A like this  `belongs_to :ref_config,:class_name => 'User'`

How can I implement the function

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), which will let you use the same `belongs_to` relation to refer to different models.

You could configure your models something like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ref_config, :polymorphic => true
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :as, :as => :ref_config
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :as, :as => :ref_config
end
```

To set up the needed columns in the `A` table, use a migration like this:

```
class CreateAs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :as do |t|
      t.string :name # or whatever other attributes A should have
      t.references :ref_config, :polymorphic => true
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :as
  end
end
```

Comment: But i have a additional request, i have two object related the user model ,one is know_user ,the  other is unknow_user

Answer (score 0):

From the little i got your question following may help you.

```
class A
  belongs_to :department_config, :class_name => 'Department', :conditions=> flag= 1
  belongs_to :user_config, :class_name => 'User', :conditions=> flag= 2
end
```